# ("Django tried these URL patterns... The empty path didn't match any of these.") How to fix "Page not found (404)" error

Tags: python, django

I am using Visual Studio Code for a basic Django project and whenever I try to run the server it gives the error:

> Page not found (404)
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
> Using the URLconf defined in startup.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
> login/
> admin/
> The empty path didn’t match any of these.
> You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

**But I wrote the code correctly**

***landing app folder views file code:***

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
    
# Create your views here.
    
def loginpage (request):
    return render (request, 'login.html')
```

**landing app file urls.py code**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from. import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',views.loginpage, name="login" ),
```

***landing app file login.html code***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Login </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

***main project urls.py file code***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',include('landing.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Your application defines the urls `login/` and `admin/`, but you're trying to access the plain url `/` which is not defined.

Comment: In others words, you can only access to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin`  as defined explicitly in your project `urls.py` file.

Comment: If I try to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/login it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try changing

> from. import views

to

> from . import views

Answer (score 0):

Try Saving all your files urls.py,login.py on vscode(ctrl+s) and then run the webpage again

Answer (score 0):

Look at the photos from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp0GX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Y02.png)

Instead of pools in your case it is login. So make sure you reach page http://localhost:8000/login/ and not http://localhost:8000/ or just use

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('landing.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in *main project urls.py file code* it's missing root path in urlpatterns. Solution:
Change from

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('login/',include('landing.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

to

```
urlpatterns = [
            path('',include('landing.urls')),
            path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

Answer (score 0):

i got into the same issue while i was building my portfolio.
(Django)
actually what happened was, i provided different links in navbar and urls.py.
solution : in

urls.py
path('home.html', views.home, name='home'),

and in navbar

Home

the link should match each other here  home.html

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',include('landing.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Try this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('landing.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: While your code may fix the problem, there is no explanation for the OP about _how_ it fixes it.  Good answers help the OP and future visitors to increase their knowledge, not just copy-paste solutions.